# Strange Situation with sp_WhoIsActive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-whoisactive

I'm with a simple task to migrate databases.

I'm doing the backup in the primary database, setting it to OFFLINE, and then, migrating it to the secondary.

No problem at all.

but I notice something strange.

I check if someone is using the database with `sp_WhoIsActive`, and it shows nothing.

Then I use `alter database X set offline`.

Then it doesn't change it at all, and the query keeps running. Then I check again to see if something is using the database, and for my surprise, it shows something running for 22hrs, 20hrs, or 44min.

Why doesn't `sp_WhoIsActive` show it?

---

Example:

1st run:

[image]

Then `Alter etc etc set offline`. Then it locks, and I check again with 
`sp_WhoIsActive`

[image]

Bam. Something running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong -- you just have to read the documentation. By default, you don't see sleeping SPIDs *unless* they're blocking another request.

The SPID you're looking at is likely a sleeping session.

Try running

`EXEC dbo.sp_WhoIsActive @show_sleeping_spids = 1`

More to your problem, you might want to set the database to single user before trying to set it offline.

Answer (score 1):

> > > More to your problem, you might want to set the database to single user before trying to set it offline.

It will not solve the problem, it's the same: trying to set database offline or in single_user, if there are (sleeping)sessions [any user connected to that database, for example, just open a query window using context of that database], they have S-lock on the database, and the session executing ALTER DATABASE will be block because it needs X-lock on the database; what you should do instead is to use

```
alter database ... set offline with rollback immediate
```

So the blocking sessions will be rolled back and release S-locks on that database

Comment: This could be a comment on erik's answer, but thanks. I completely forgot about rollback immediate.